# Dropping underlying containers in range-v3 zip

Tags: c++, c++20, range-v3

This seems impossible, but just wanted to check.

If I want to drop first 3 elements of vector I can do it easily:

```
void drop_vec() {
    std::vector v {1,2,3,4,5};
    actions::drop(v,3);
    fmt::print("{} \n", v);
}
```

This is the action so container is modified.

Similar logic can be done for views:

```
void drop_view_() {
    auto indexes = views::iota(1,6);
    auto dropped_indexes = views::drop(indexes,3);
    fmt::print("{} \n", dropped_indexes);
}
```

This also works for zip views:

```
void drop_zip_view_view() {
    auto indexes = views::iota(1,6);
    auto indexes2 = views::iota(2,7);
    auto dropped_indexes = views::zip(indexes,indexes2) | views::drop(3);
    fmt::print("{} \n", dropped_indexes);
}
```

Problem arises when I want to mutate the underlying containers in the zipped view.
I tried seeing if range-v3 has something like `zip_range`, but it seems only available thing is `zip_view`.

So is it possible to implement `action::drop` like functionality (so underlying containers are modified) in this case:

```
void drop_zip_vec_vec() {
    std::vector v {1,2,3,4,5};
    std::vector v2 {2,3,4,5,6};
    // how to drop elements from zip of both containers?
}
```

[godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/vPz46qjnx)

note: I know I can call `action::drop` for each vector manually, but beside it being ugly it will also not guarantee same number of elements is removed from both containers(e.g. if one container has 5 elements other 3 and I call drop with 4 first container will have 1 instead of 2 elements remaining).

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `drop_zip_view_view` code, and then "unzip" the resulting list of pairs into the original vectors through:

- `views::keys` and `views::values` for the unzipping, and
- `ranges::to` for the vector updating.

[[Demo]](https://godbolt.org/z/6MPGz1a4z)

```cpp
void drop_zip_vec_vec() {
    std::vector v{1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
    std::vector v2{2, 3, 4, 5, 6};
    auto dropped_vs = views::zip(v, v2) | views::drop(3);
    v = views::keys(dropped_vs) | ranges::to<std::vector>();
    v2 = views::values(dropped_vs) | ranges::to<std::vector>();
    fmt::print("drop_zip_vec_vec:\n\tv: {}\n\tv2: {}\n", v, v2);
}

// Outputs:
//
//   drop_view_:
//      [4, 5]
//   drop_vec:
//      [4, 5]
//   drop_zip_view_view:
//      [(4, 5), (5, 6)]
//   drop_zip_vec_vec:
//      v: [4, 5]
//      v2: [5, 6]
```

Comment: nice, but that might be a bit inefficient for containers like deque that support efficient removal from front(in case I remove 1% of elements from front). Still upvoted, will probably accept since I doubt there is a better way. :/

Comment: That's a good point. I don't know if templatizing `drop_zip` and specializing for `deque` (after measuring and deciding it's worth it) would be an option for you.